# Create Nullschool Earth flowlines over displacement map

Tags: displacement

[image]

I am trying to create a static image of wind flowing over a topographical surface. I am new to blender but can get by with the basics. I tried particle animations but had little sucess. Can anyone kindly point me in right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution but if you're only interested in a static image, you could use the wind map images as textures and UV unwrap the surface onto it.

Worst case scenario...you could try texture painting all the lines. Don't recommend that though, especially if you need it to be accurate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out. It does not need to be accurate, just needs to look good and follow the topography. Cheers